# Adding interceptor to routes in Ktor not working

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have a `Route` where for every `ApplicationCall` I'd like to add a header to the response.

e.g.

```
routes {
   route("/cdn-cached") {
        intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features){
           call.response.header(HttpHeaders.CacheControl, ...)
        }
        

        get(...) {...}
        post(...) {...}
        route(...) {...}
   }
}
```

This is an oversimplified example of a setup I have, but what I expect is that every time I call an endpoint under the `/cdn-cached` route it gets the header attached. I am sure I mess up something, but I don't know what.

What do I need to fix this code?

Note: I have a framework that does a lot of dynamic things, so far it could do everything I wanted, now I got stumbled on this one. I just tell this because it is not a good option for me to add the header in every individual `ApplicationCall` like the get, post and route here. I could do that, but I'd prefer not to if I can just do it similarly to what I described in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept the `ApplicationCallPipeline.Call` phase to affect current route and its child routes:

```
route("/cdn-cached") {
    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
        call.response.header("custom", "123")
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick, however in the docs it says that something like mine should work: https://ktor.io/docs/intercepting-routes.html#intercepting-any-route-node 

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I've updated the answer. There is no need to intercept all child routes.

Comment: It is weird, it works in a normal setup but in my framework when I add it dynamically it does not.